# "Carpenters love the tools they use to build houses with."

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence, "with" is necessary?

> Carpenters love the tools they use to build houses with.

Answer (score 1):

This is the given sentence:

> *Carpenters love the tools they use to build houses **with**.

The "with" is not necessary and should not be there. The sentence mixes up two different structures:
**1) Carpenters love the tools they build houses with.**
That sentence has a reduced relative clause modifying "tools", and it is equivalent to
*Carpenters love the tools with which they build houses.*

**2) Carpenters love they tools they use to build houses.**
That sentence has a relative clause with the to-infinitival "to build houses" as a purpose adjunct, which modifies "tools".
The word "**with**" has no place in that sentence.