# with is necessary or not

Tags: grammar

In the following sentences, with is necessary?

1. He needs the tools to build the house with.
2. He uses the tools to build the house with.

Answer (score -1):

This question is similar to one you asked recently:
[Stackexchange ELL "to...with"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/251989/carpenters-love-the-tools-they-use-to-build-houses-with)

Here, you are asking about these examples:

1. He needs the tools to build the house with.
2. He uses the tools to build the house with.

The word "with" is not needed in either of the sentences. It could be used in example 1, but it isn't necessary. It is incorrect and should not be used in example 2.